# libstdc++ 64bit and 32bit version on the same machine

Tags: c++, build-process, 64-bit, linker, 32-bit

I am trying to cross compile a version of my software for a 64bit platform. Can I have the 32bit and 64bit version of libstdc++ installed on the same machine without too much worries of breaking my linux install. The Os is 32bit ubuntu.

I have not cross compiled before and just wanted to check that if I set my CFLAGS and LDFLAGS
for the appropriate CPU I should be ok once I have the correct versions of libstdc++ installed.

I checked a 64bit version of ubuntu however this has a symbolic link

lib64 -> lib

this would mess up lots if this is the case on a 32bit machine too anyone know how to sort this?

I am hitting the following error at the moment

> ```
>  [exec] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/libstdc++.so
>  [exec] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.2.4/libstdc++.a
>  when searching for -lstdc++ [exec] /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
> ```
>
> and so on till

```
 [exec] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
 [exec] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which seems to be due to fact I do not have the 64bit version of libstdc++

Comment: for some reason it seems like some,if not all, I
Unbuntu distros lack Lib64. Don't use it myself but similar questions have been asked here about the 64bit libs. Anyways toucan have both installed, no problem in theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.

Just put them into `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64`, respectively.

Can't check it on `Ubuntu`, but on `Fedora` they get there right from the packages:

```
[~#] repoquery -q -l libstdc++.i386
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10

[~#] repoquery -q -l libstdc++.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
```

Comment: I'll be apt getting them do you know if this happens by default on ubuntu?